# Rythm template engine define custom method in Java code

Tags: template-engine, rythm

I know there is the possibility to define a method in templates like this:

```
@def myMethod(String parameter){
     before @parameter after 
}
```

and use it:

```
@myMethod("my object")
```

This will output: 
`before my object after`
Can I define the `myMethod` in Java code and use it in multiple templates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to define that method in Java code. Instead in your rythm [template home directory](http://rythmengine.org/doc/configuration.md#home_template_dir) create a file named `__global.rythm`, and define that method there, then all your rythm template will automatically pick up that method because `__global.rythm` will be `@include` by Rythm engine in every template automatically. Below is a real global rythm file from my project:

```
@import com.abc.model.*
@import org.rythmengine.spring.web.Csrf
@import org.rythmengine.RythmEngine
@import com.abc.AppConfig
@import com.abc.model.color.*;
@args Csrf csrf


@def String csrfParam() {
  return "__csrf=" + ((null == csrf) ? "nocsrf" : csrf.value);
}

@def RythmEngine rythm() {
  return __engine();
}

@def User me() {
  return User.me();
}

@def boolean loggedIn() {
  return User.me() != null;
}

@def String host() {
  return com.abc.AppConfig.host()
}
```